# How do you convert to percentage by using COUNT in SQL?

Tags: sql, percentage

For example, if I want to list the percentages of males and females in the 'Employee' table.
Is this right?

```
SELECT Sex, COUNT (Sex) AS [%]
FROM Employees
GROUP BY Sex;
```

And what if I want to list the gender that is less than 50%? Is the following correct?

```
SELECT Sex, COUNT (Sex) AS [%]
FROM Employees
GROUP BY Sex
HAVING COUNT (Sex) < 50%
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried it ? I don't think it would work. The percentage your looking for would be the result of the division of the count by the number of answers , multiplied by 100. I don't think this is possible without a subquery though

Comment: What would be the column type? Bit? VARCHAR?

Comment: What RDBMS and version are you using?

Comment: No, I haven't. I'm studying old exam papers and I saw an answer like this. I'm curious % can be used this way in SQL. Can you answer it in the way you said? I don't know how to write that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

```
SELECT Sex, (Count(Sex)* 100 / (SELECT Count(*) FROM Employees)) as MyPercentage
FROM Employees
GROUP BY Sex
```

Then you can do

```
HAVING MyPercentage < 50
```

Comment: Do I have to include ['%'] at the end or the result would be just a number with no '%' symbol'?

Comment: The result in this solution is only a value, so it does not include the percent sign

Answer (score 1):

No.  Most versions of SQL support window functions.  You can calculate the percentages using the following:

```
SELECT Sex, COUNT(Sex)/(sum(count(sex)) over ()) AS [%]
FROM Employees
GROUP BY Sex;
```

(I'm leaving out the `100*`, because I'm not sure if you want a percentage between 0 and 100 or a probability between 0 and 1.)

Some versions of SQL do integer division, in which case you need to convert this to a decimal or float:

```
SELECT Sex, cast(COUNT(Sex) as float)/(sum(count(sex)) over ()) AS [%]
FROM Employees
GROUP BY Sex;
```

Comment: Why the double `COUNT`?: `(count(count(sex)) over ())`

Comment: I think he is trying to get the SUM( COUNT() ), in others words, the number of employees. But it isn't valid because you can't use aggregate functions that way. @Christopher Bales has correctly answered

Comment: @Utopik Well, actually you _can_ use aggregate functions that way using `OVER()`, but Christopher's solution is more portable.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson you're right, I just changed "can't" with "shouldn't"  :) (or not, I _can't_ edit anymore)

Comment: @Utopik . . . Not only is it correct.  In databases that support window functions, this version is likely to be faster.  And, if a database supports ANSI standard windows functions, then this syntax is allowed.  It counts as quite portable.